Lipschitz Domain and Sobolev Spaces
In theory of PDEs, we usually impose some smoothness assumptions on the domain $\Omega$, so that the standard Theorems involving Sobolev Spaces hold true, like continuous/compact embedding theorems, trace theorems, extension theorems etc. The usual generalization, or the weakest condition we impose, in introductory textbooks, uses the so called Lipshitz domain, a class of domain that satisfies the strong cone condition and often remark after these classes of theorem states that, one can obtain similar result by assuming the domain is weakly Lipchitz, which I am not very familiar with.
One common example of non-Lipshitz domain that usual embedding theorem fails is the following:
Consider the domain $ D_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $ 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq x^\alpha$, for any $ \alpha > 1 $. $D_\alpha$ has a sharp edge at $0$ so it is not Lipshitz. One can prove by direct calculation that $ W^{1,p}(D_\alpha) \not\subset L^{q^\ast} (D_\alpha) $ for $ 1 \leq p < 2 $ and $ 1/q^\ast = 1/p - 1/2 $ which is the optimal exponent one can obtain on Lipshitz domain. In fact one can prove that $ W^{1,p}(D_\alpha) \hookrightarrow L^{q_\alpha}(D_\alpha) $ for $ 1/q_\alpha = 1/p - 1/(1+\alpha) $ and $ W^{1,p}(D_\alpha) \not\subset L^q(D_\alpha)$ for all $q$ such that $ q > q_\alpha $. In some sense, functions defined on $D_\alpha$ lose more regularity than dimension $2$ by having a sharp edge.
Question 1:
What's the difference between the results assuming Lipshitz domain and weakly Lipshitz domain? Does the result not longer hold true and only weaker result is true? Or does it make the proof significantly technical?
Question 2:
What result no longer holds true if (weakly) Lipshitz condition is not satisfied? What result do we have in that case? Can we quantify the lost of regularity like the example above for any Sobolev/Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces? perhaps using some generalized cone condition using cones with "sharp top" just like $D_\alpha$?
Any further remarks, comments and references on this topic is more than welcome. Thank you!
